# Python self monitoring class

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a class that can
1.  Keep itself alive
2.  monitor itself periodically and do stuff to correct itself (ie data stops coming in, respawn self)

I am currently doing it like this:

```
class SelfMonitorClass(object):
    exit_flag = False

    def __init__(self):
        self.flush_timer = 10 # in seconds, how often we should check ourselves!
        self.perpetual_runner()

    def do_actions(self):
        # do stuff! add things together
        # check that temperature ect is in some range 
        print('I AM DOING AN ACTION!')

    def perpetual_runner(self):
        self.do_actions() # actually go do something!!
        if self.exit_flag == False: # POISON PILL check
            athread = threading.Timer(self.flush_timer,  self.perpetual_runner);
            athread.daemon = True
            athread.start()
    def kill(self)
        self.exit_flag = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    aclass = SelfMonitorClass()

    print('Main thread exits!')

>>>> 'I AM DOING SOMETHING' 
>>>> 'Main thread exits!'
>>>> 'I AM DOING SOMETHING' # repeat every 10 seconds, while console is still up.  Regardless of the fact '__main__' is done.
```

Is this way of doing things a good idea?  Should I implement something like this another way?  The attribute that life continues on while it keeps itself alive is very important to me.

Also if there packages that can take care of something like this for me would be awesome!

Killing this program is rather annoying (find processes, sigTERM/sigKILL.  stuff like that),  but that's not the major concern here.  just keeping the thread alive and periodically checking internal states and doing something is.

Comment: If self.do_actions() dead loop, then never check self.exit_flag == False, then never monitor.

Comment: @PastBT, do you mean if in self.do_actions(), I stick a while True loop in there?  In that case my program will never end - a bug in programming and not intended behavior.

Comment: dispatching `KeyboardInterrupt`s to child threads/processes is not possible.  It will only be raised in your main thread.  You will need to roll your own solution for killing your worker, i.e. creating/checking a [named pipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.mkfifo) for a kill instruction.

Comment: @roippi definitely.  that's not a major worry for me.  it's just keeping the thread alive and managing state periodically

Comment: @yaccz,  daemontools just helps me run the file?  It is probably better than doing a cronjob,  but I dont think I can change internal states of what is running with daemontools can i?

Comment: it will keep a process running by spawning it immediately again once it exits for whatever reason.